# Starling and Box2d on iOS - terribly slow

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, starling-framework

Using FlashDevelop with Starling and Box2d I created a simple billiard pool game.

It runs fine in the desktop flash player.

When converted to iOS and tested on the latest iPad, it runs really slow.

Having just 15 ball bodies on the stage, the frame rate falls to below 20 fps.

My settings are pretty much standard...

Why? Any advice?

Mirza

Comment: Make sure you compile it as a Release Build. There's a huge difference between Debug and Release builds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your version of starling, which is 1.4.

**http://gamua.com/starling/download/**

and make sure you have export as a Release build than fast build as KumoKairo have been mentioned.

The performance should be pretty good especially on iPad4 hardware.

Comment: how do I test a release built, I thought release buildts must be first submitted to the app store to be able to download them, right?

Comment: @mirzahat you just build your release build with your provision profile, it works :) not your distribution one

Comment: But what option do I need to select in the packager? https://www.dropbox.com/s/djzl96f59bv91g8/list.JPG

Comment: http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=AS3_Conditional_Compilation  check this out mate, do you have flash builder or flash pro its quite easy to do in there.